# How to prove that the function $f(x)=0.1\,e^{-0.2|x|} $ is a probability density, and then use it?

Tags: probability, integration

So here's the integral, I'm having a hard time solving it. I even tried integration software, but it didn't help:

$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx,\qquad f(x)=0.1\,e^{-0.2|x|} $$

The question states two things:

1) Prove it is a pdf, by ensuring the integration = 1

2) What proportion of errors are negative ? At most 2?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Please walk me through what you are doing as well

Comment: Errors of what?

Comment: Sorry, I guess to understand my question, you have to know the context.

Comment: "What proportion of errors are negative ? At most 2?": a proportion uses to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: The introduction stated: "The article ' Error Distribution in Navigation' suggests that the frequency distribution of positive errors (magnitudes of errors) is well approximated by the distribution f(x) [refer above for function], where x represents the lateral position errors (nautical miles), which can be either positive or negative."

Comment: Standard textbook shorthand for two questions...  What proportion of errors are negative?  What proportion of errors are at most 2?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\, \left| x \right| }
}{dx}=\int _{-\infty }^{0}\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{ 0.2\,x}}{dx}+\int _{0}^{
\infty }\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\,x}}{dx} 
$$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\, \left| x \right| }
}{dx}={\frac {1}{2}}\int _{-\infty }^{0}\! 0.2\,{{\rm e}^{ 0.2\,x}}{dx}+{\frac {1}{2}}\int _{0}^{
\infty }\! 0.2\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\,x}}{dx} 
$$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\, \left| x \right| }
}{dx}={\frac {1}{2}}({{\rm e}^{ 0.2\,(0)}}-{{\rm e}^{ 0.2\,(-\infty )}})-{\frac {1}{2}}({{\rm e}^{ -0.2\,(\infty )}}-{{\rm e}^{ 0.2\,(0 )}})
$$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! 0.1\,{{\rm e}^{- 0.2\, \left| x \right| }
}{dx}={\frac {1}{2}}(1-0)-{\frac {1}{2}}(0-1)=1
$$

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is the first step how would you actually integrate the function ? Is it a u-substitution ?

Comment: Could you show me the steps of integration, so I could better understand ?

Comment: On each side this is a very simple u-substitution, $u=0.2x$. This is the same as you would use to prove that the usual exponential density is a density.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {1}{10} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-0.2 (abs(x)} dx$$

But $e^{-.2 abs(x)}$ is an even function and the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ is symmetric about $0$,  $$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-0.2 abs(x)} dx = 2 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-.2 abs(x)}  dx$$

So now we have $$ \frac15 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x/5}  dx$$

Substitute $u=-\frac {x}{5}$ and  $du = -\frac15  dx$

Change the bounds and you get;

$$-\int_0^{-\infty} e^u  du$$ then switch the bounds;

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^u du= \lim_{n \to -\infty} \int_n^0 e^u du = \lim_{n \to -\infty} e^u|_n^0= 1-(\lim_{n \to -\infty} e^n)= 1-0=1$$

For 2) I literally have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Hey,I should I have included the context of the question. The introduction was:

Comment: "The article ' Error Distribution in Navigation' suggests that the frequency distribution of positive errors (magnitudes of errors) is well approximated by the distribution f(x) [refer above for function], where x represents the lateral position errors (nautical miles), which can be either positive or negative." Does 2) make more sense now?

Comment: Not really, according to this it is obviously $\frac12$(because of its symmetry), however the 2) shouldn't be that trivial with respect to 1).

Comment: That is true.Anyways, Thanks for the answer for 1), it was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

To prove it is a density function:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10} e^{-|x|/5}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10} e^{-x/5}dx = -e^{x/5}|_{0}^{\infty} = 1$$
For the second part of the question, the statement isn't clear but presumably "errors" means that this is a distribution of errors, in which case the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ since $f$ is symmetric so exactly half of the probability mass is on the negative side.

Answer (score 0):

A contrieved approach:

First derive the exponential to understand how to handle the absolute value:
$$e^{-a|x|}=-a\ sgn(x)e^{-a|x|}.$$
Then the antiderivative could be
$$\int e^{-a|x|}dx=-\frac{sgn(x)}ae^{-a|x|},$$
but this is not correct because there is a discontinuity at $0$.

We can fix it by adding a sign function (having a null derivative) with a suitable coefficient:
$$\int e^{-a|x|}dx=sgn(x)\frac{1-e^{-a|x|}}a.$$
The discontinuity is gone and the derivative remains right.
Now we can get the improper integral,
$$sgn(x)\frac{1-e^{-a|x|}}a\Big|_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac1a-(-\frac1a)=\frac2a.$$
From this result we can get the cdf,
$$\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-a|t|}dt=\frac{sgn(x)(1-e^{-a|x|})+1}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

In a probability course, for the integral there is basically nothing to do. By symmetry, our integral is 
$$\int_0^\infty (0.2)e^{-0.2 x}\,dx.$$
Since $(0.2)e^{-0.2 x}$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$ is the density function of a well-known distribution (exponential, parameter $0.2$), the integral is $1$.